# VueJs - Prepend to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to prepend data to an array in VueJs:

```
number: [

],

this.number.push({
    number: 1
})
```

How do I prepend rather than append?

Comment: Push does append to an array... what is the behavior you want?

Answer (score 30):

Unshift:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

```
this.number.unshift({number: 1});
```

You can also pass multiple arguments to add them all:

```
this.number.unshift({number: 1}, {number: 2});
```

The return value is the new length of the array:

```
var foo = [1];
var bar = foo.unshift(2, 3, 4);
//foo = [2, 3, 4, 1]; bar = 4;
```

Comment: @user3662307 remember: unshift, shift, push and pop

Answer (score 2):

Vue wraps an observed only this Array methods: `push, pop, shift, unshift, splice, sort, reverse`. You can use unshift or splice. For example:

```
 youArray.splice(0, 0, 'first item in Array');
```

Answer (score 0):

Unshift is the good solution. But here is a different solution using concat:

```
this.number = [{number: 1}].concat(this.number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also add the new way of prepending to an array:

```
this.number = [
 { number: 1 },
  ...this.number
]
```